# Republish only failed element with project reactor flux's retry?

Tags: project-reactor, reactive

I have a processor and a sink that emits elements with sink.next().

The flux could potentially fail on one of the steps, I want to retry only the failed element and not the rest.[image]

On the image above I want only to re-emit the purple element.

Comment: Why would you emit the purple element twice?

Comment: @abetteroliver because probably I called a webservice that timed out, and I want to retry the call

Comment: The purple element doesn't fail. It seems that the image doesn't describe your use case.